# SVM with probability estimates

Tags: weka, svm, svmlight

I have a binary classification problem i am solving with SVM. The classes are unbalanced in the training data. I now need to get posterior probabilities outputs, and not just a binary score. I tried to use Platt scaling by either Weka's SMO, and LibSVM. For both of these implementations i get results which, in terms of f1-measure for the minority class, are worse then when i generated only binary results.

Do you know of a way to transform SVM binary results to probabilities which keeps the next rule:
"prob > = 0.5 if and only if decision value >= 0".

Meaning that the label the each sample gets is the same when using either binary classification, or probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

SVM can be set so that they output class membership probabilities. You should look documentation of your toolkit to learn how to enable this.

For example [sckit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#scores-probabilities)

> When the constructor option probability is set to True, class
>   membership probability estimates (from the methods predict_proba and
>   predict_log_proba) are enabled.

Comment: I used this setting both in weka's SMO and in LibSVM. There, and also in sckit-learn, the implementation is of Platt scaling. The problem with this solution is that it gives different results comparing to the binary results case.

Comment: @Yonanam: I know that behaviour for libSVM. But why is it a problem? Is the classifier with probability performing significantly worse?

Comment: @stefan: Yes, the performance in terms of f1 measure for the minority class is worse. I think this is because the data is unbalanced, and fitting a logit function is problematic this way.